# How to Uninstall Nginx from Ubuntu 12.04 and Recover Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have Installed Ruby,Rails in my Laptop , I'm Not familiar with Ubuntu, when I install Ruby an Nginx also installed without my permission, Im a PHP programmer now my apache overwritten by Nginx  , plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nginx installation should not overwrite any apache files. I bet you just have to stop it and start apache.

Stop nginx

```
/usr/bin/nginx -s stop
```

Start apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

You can also use restart and stop instead of start

Make shure the

```
apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

file is correct

To uninstall nginx

```
sudo rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx && rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```